# Papaja duplicating references

Tags: reference, duplicates

Papaja has recently started duplicating references for me and my students. None of us have a clue where to start to trouble-shoot this. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug [#338](https://github.com/crsh/papaja/issues/338) that should be fixed now. Updating papaja via `devtools::install_github("crsh/papaja")` should therefore solve the problem.